react localhost https net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
I am currently implementing a website using React and Spring as a team project.
Since https is required on localhost for social login and project invitation, I issued a self-signed certificate using mkcert and applied it to localhost. I was then able to run https localhost by adding a command to start my package.json with https.
    "craco-dev": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=localhost.pem&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=localhost-key.pem&&cross-env NODE_ENV=development craco start",

It worked without a problem for a few days, but one day when I tried to log in to the React app, the following error message occurred.
${SERVER_API} net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I also confirmed that https appears in the browser search bar and that the message “Your connection is secure” appears when you hover over the lock on the left.
So I googled and did the following:

In edge (currently localhost is running on edge) settings, add the certificate you use for React HTTPS to the list of trusted certificates
Replace mkcert certificate with openssl certificate
Delete edge cookies and site data

Even if I did the above, the error remained the same. So, I would like to ask whether it is difficult to run HTTPS on localhost with a self-signed certificate, or if there is a way to solve the problem.
Also, not only I but other team members are using the app, so I'm curious if this is the cause.
